# Is there anything interesting about the limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\Big|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{|h|}\Big|$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was wondering if there is anything interesting to say about the following limit:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, and $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\Big|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{|h|}\Big|$$

---

If $f$ is differentiable I don't think the limit needs to converge. Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\Big|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{|h|}\Big|=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\Big|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-T(h)}{|h|}-\frac{|h|T(u)}{|h|}\Big|=\Big|T(u)\Big|$$
where $u$ is the unit vector in the direction of $h$. So the direction at which the limit is taken matters.

Answer (score 1):

If f is from Rn it needs to take n values, so the equation doesnt make sense for n not equal 1, for n = 1 this is a derivative which is think is pretty intresting.

Edit:
if you mean that h is being added to one element of a this is a partial derivative, and if it is added to all elements of a than without deviding by h this is something known as the total diffrential

Comment: That's why i edited the answer